# Call the object inside the library by code

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, object, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I am a newbie. I'm on my project to make a interactive map. I do not want to make it with a many objects, but by the code. I want to ask you, is it possible to show the object in library by the code? 
If so, how to call it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Var instanceName = new LibraryName();
/* give it the properties you need */ 
stage.addChild(instanceName);
```

the instance name will be the name that you want it to take for your project
the library name is the name of the object in your library.
stage.addChild() is the function that allow you to add the object to the stage

Comment: how if, I have an object inside the library named "map". Then I want to call it to the stage by the code when I click a button. So, what code I should type? Is it look like this? if(home_btn.Click){var map = new map(); stage.addChild(map_mc);} @NicolasSleiman

Comment: Yes @EmmaBarus this should do it

Comment: you should export it to actionscript in the properties. to access properties right click on the symbol in the library and click porporties then check export for action script @EmmaBarus

Comment: what things that I should export? Can you tell me more detail, please? @NicolasSleiman

Comment: right click on the symbol that you want to add from the code, then click on properties, then check the box export for actionscript 3 @EmmaBarus

Answer (score 0):

You must give the object an AS Linkage, if you already done that, then you can refer that as a Class, like:
`var clubPoint:CLUBOBJECT = new CLUBOBJECT();`
The programming IDE will not recognize the class, but upon compiling and testing the file in Adobe Flash Pro CSx, CSx will automatically generate a new class for it, and thus you can use it.

Comment: then how to give AS linkage to the object? @Zhafur

Comment: In the library, right next to it's name, there is another collumn named AS Linkage. Or right click->properties->actioscript(tab)->Class.

Comment: Do you mean making a class file, don't you? @Zhafur

Comment: You don't have to make a class file for it, if you give it a linkage and the compiler doesn't find it when it compiles the program, then it will automatically generate one for itself.